# Remove vertical spacing of theorem-like environment inside a list

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

I'm using a custom "claim"-environment which I want to use in the document. Beside the usage inside the document, I also want to use this claim environment inside a list. My question is: How do I remove the additional horizontal spacing between the bullet of the list and the word "claim"?

[image]

The vertical spacing should not be larger than the spacing before normal text would be.

Here is a full working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem, etoolbox, thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}

\newlist{Claim}{description}{3}% allow 3 levels of nesting
\setlist[Claim]{labelindent=2em,leftmargin=*}

\newcounter{claimlevel}% records nesting level
\newcounter{claimi}[theorem] % claim counters for each nesting level
\newcounter{claimii}[claimi]
\newcounter{claimiii}[claimii]
\renewcommand\theclaimi{\arabic{claimi}}
\renewcommand\theclaimii{\theclaimi.\arabic{claimii}}
\renewcommand\theclaimiii{\theclaimii.\arabic{claimiii}}
\let\originalqedsymbol\qedsymbol
\newenvironment{claim}{%
  % disable qed symbol if there is no star
  \let\qedsymbol\relax%
  \stepcounter{claimlevel}
  \refstepcounter{claim\roman{claimlevel}}%
  \Claim\item[\textbf{Claim \csuse{theclaim\roman{claimlevel}}:}]%
  }{\endClaim\addtocounter{claimlevel}{-1}\let\qedsymbol\originalqedsymbol}

\newcommand\claimiautorefname{Claim}
\newcommand\claimiiautorefname{Claim}
\newcommand\claimiiiautorefname{Claim}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \begin{claim}
        
    \end{claim}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

### **EDIT**:

I've tried to create a separate claim environment for the usage inside lists:

```
\newlist{listclaim}{description}{3}% allow 3 levels of nesting
\setlist[listclaim]{labelindent=2em,leftmargin=*}

\newcounter{listclaimlevel}% records nesting level
\newcounter{listclaimi}[theorem] % listclaim counters for each nesting level
\newcounter{listclaimii}[listclaimi]
\newcounter{listclaimiii}[listclaimii]
\renewcommand\thelistclaimi{\arabic{listclaimi}}
\renewcommand\thelistclaimii{\thelistclaimi.\arabic{listclaimii}}
\renewcommand\thelistclaimiii{\thelistclaimii.\arabic{listclaimiii}}
\let\originalqedsymbol\qedsymbol
\newenvironment{listclaim}{%
  % disable qed symbol if there is no star
  \let\qedsymbol\relax%
  \stepcounter{listclaimlevel}
  \refstepcounter{listclaim\roman{listclaimlevel}}%
  \listclaim\item[\textbf{listclaim \csuse{thelistclaim\roman{listclaimlevel}}:}]%
  }{\endlistclaim\addtocounter{listclaimlevel}{-1}\let\qedsymbol\originalqedsymbol}

\newcommand\listclaimiautorefname{listclaim}
\newcommand\listclaimiiautorefname{listclaim}
\newcommand\listclaimiiiautorefname{listclaim}
```

But now I'm receiving the error "command`\listclaim` already defined". I don't get that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `command \listclaim already defined` comes from defining the new list and the new environment with the same name, If you will replace `\newenvironment{listclaim}{%` with `\newenvironment{Listclaim}{%` there is no error, but I don't see how it solves the first problem.

I suggest using trivial lists here, I used a similar code to the definition of theorems from the LaTeX kernel, but using a different format for the counters, and prepended `\item` with `\normalfont` so so the label will be typeset with the right font

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}

\newenvironment{claim}{%
    \let\qedsymbol\relax
    \stepcounter{claimlevel}%
    \refstepcounter{claim\roman{claimlevel}}%
    \normalfont\trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep{\bfseries Claim \UseName{theclaim\roman{claimlevel}}:}]\itshape\ignorespaces
}{%
    \endtrivlist\addtocounter{claimlevel}{-1}%
}

\newcounter{claimlevel}% records nesting level
\newcounter{claimi}[theorem] % claim counters for each nesting level
\newcounter{claimii}[claimi]
\newcounter{claimiii}[claimii]
\renewcommand\theclaimi{\arabic{claimi}}
\renewcommand\theclaimii{\theclaimi.\arabic{claimii}}
\renewcommand\theclaimiii{\theclaimii.\arabic{claimiii}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \begin{claim}\begin{claim}
                test
            \end{claim}
        \begin{claim}
            test
            \begin{claim}
                test
            \end{claim}
        \end{claim}
        \end{claim}
    \item test
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still need that the claim environment works as it does before at any other place in my document (i.e. outside a list). Why can't we declare two different such claim environments? Or can we?

Comment: @0xbadf00d How should it work outside of lists? or even better, can you specify what is missing with this approach?

Comment: @0xbadf00d See my edit

Comment: It should have the indent outside the list. Regarding your edit: Why do I need to replace `\newenvironment{listclaim}{%` by `\newenvironment{Listclaim}{%`? The only modification is the capitalization of `l` ... I'm very confused by this. The same in my question: I first declared `\newlist{claim}`. Why can I now not declare `\newlist{listclaim}`? The names "claim" and "listclaim" are different aren't they? Don't get it.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The conflict is between `\newlist{listclaim}` and `\newenvironment{listclaim}`, it has noting to do with `\newlist{claim}`.

Comment: That would be clear to me, but that's not the problem. Look, I've got the `\newlist{Claim}` thing of my question. And now I've added your solution as well, **but** with every occurrence of the word "claim" replaced by "listclaim" (i.e. "claimlevel" replaced by "listclaimlevel", and so on). But when I now use the "listclaim"-environment inside a "itemize" environment, it does not work; this is the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVs1o.png. (I'm not receiving the "already defined" error mentioned before though)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143285/discussion-between-udi-fogiel-and-0xbadf00d).

Comment: May I ask you another question? I need to add two more levels to the claim environment. I've done the obvious and added `\newcounter{listclaimiv}[listclaimiii]`, `\newcounter{listclaimv}[listclaimiv]`, `\renewcommand\thelistclaimiv{\thelistclaimiii.\arabic{listclaimiv}}`, `\renewcommand\thelistclaimv{\thelistclaimiv.\arabic{listclaimv}}`, `\newcommand\listclaimivautorefname{Claim}`, `\newcommand\listclaimvautorefname{Claim}`. However, now the bullet points of the surrounding lists are not shown for those claims with level $\ge4$. Any reason for this?